# How infants can take 11mg of Iron per day?

Tags: infant, food, nutrition, weaning

According to New Zealand and Australian government guides, infants 7-12 months need 11 mg of iron daily. (Source: [NZ](https://nutritionfoundation.org.nz/nutrition-facts/nutrients/minerals/iron/), [AU](https://www.eatforhealth.gov.au/nutrient-reference-values/nutrients/iron)). According to the same sources, beef has only 2 to 3 mg of Iron per 100 grams. Or tofu has 5.4 mg per 100 gr.

So, 11 mg of Iron means 366 grams of beef or 203 grams of Tofu. Obviously, no infant can eat that much.

Am I misunderstanding something? Are my calculations wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> [babies] 7-12 months need 11 mg of iron daily.

Correct. US recommendations are the same.

> 11 mg of Iron means 366 grams of beef or 203 grams of Tofu...  Are my calculations wrong?

No, they're not. The exact number (mg/100g beef, red meat) varies significantly, with some stating less and some stating more; your value is about in the middle.

> Am I misunderstanding something?

If you're wondering how a baby can possibly get that much iron daily when even beef can't supply it, no, you're not misunderstanding. That's a *lot* of iron.

One cannot calculate the amount of iron a baby gets in their diet with any degree of accuracy, due to so very many confounding factors. For example, spinach was touted as a good source of iron when my kids were very young. Since then, the realization that the oxalic acid in spinach renders the iron non-absorbable means it's not on the list any more, unless the child is also on Vitamin C supplements. Calcium also inhibits iron absorption, which is why Pediatricians recommend that young children drink no more than 3 8-oz. servings of cow's milk/day.  And that's just the tip of the iceberg.  If you try to add up a baby's iron intake without knowing the confounding variables, that is, what is heme- and non-heme iron, and what enhances and what inhibits the absorption of iron in the gut, you'll probably be significantly off the mark.

Babies in most developed nations get their iron from iron fortified foods, primarily baby formula, baby cereals, and products made with flour (in the US, 95% of flour is "enriched" with vitamins and iron.) Even so, the majority of babies do not get sufficient iron from their diets.

Since iron deficiency in babies can be associated with numerous problems including irreversible mental, motor, and behavioral functioning, babies should be screened for iron deficiency somewhere around 12 months of age. Relying on what you've calculated as their intake is a mistake best avoided. Talk to your pediatrician *before* you rely on your calculations, not *after*.

<sub>Inhibitors of iron absorption include phytate, which is a compound found in plant-based diets that demonstrate a dose-dependent effect on iron absorption. Polyphenols are found in black and herbal tea, coffee, wine, legumes, cereals, fruit, and vegetables and have been demonstrated to inhibit iron absorption. Unlike other inhibitors such as polyphenols and phytates, which prevent only non-heme iron absorption, calcium inhibits both heme and non-heme iron at the point of initial uptake into enterocytes. Animal proteins such as casein, whey, egg whites, and proteins from plants (soy protein) have been shown to inhibit iron absorption in humans. Oxalic acid is found in spinach, chard, beans, and nuts and acts to bind and inhibit iron absorption.</sub>
<sub>Enhancers of iron absorption are dominated by the effect of ascorbic acid (vitamin C), which can overcome the effects of all dietary inhibitors when it is included in a diet with high non-heme iron availability (usually a meal heavy in vegetables).  Ascorbic acid forms a chelate with ferric (Fe3+) iron in the low pH of the stomach, which persists and remains soluble in the alkaline environment of the duodenum.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

When trying to assess things like nutrition, it’s very important to take the whole picture into account.

A typical mistake of adults on a diet is to just calculate parts of what they consume, e.g. counting calories in food but forgetting drinks or avoiding refined sugar, but eating lots of fruit.

So if you want to calculate the iron in your baby’s food, you need to measure *everything* the child consumes, including cereal, milk, etc., and not just one food item. And ideally track it over a certain time frame to get a reliable average. Do not look at one source of iron etc. without context.

You will probably (hopefully) find out that the numbers add up to the given recommendations. If not, *then* talk to you pediatrician whether tests should be done and get their opinion on whether you need to adjust the child’s diet or add supplements.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145032/discussion-on-answer-by-stephie-how-infants-can-take-11mg-of-iron-per-day); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.